# R move/shift values into other column within lapply

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

**Project Overview:**

I'm working on a document extraction project using the docxtractr library to extract word tables from multiple files and turn them into a data frame. The below code is for a specific table, the 6th table.

Due to the multiple files I'm using **lapply** to iterate over each one and complete data frame manipulation tasks. The reason the data frame has an extra column is because there are hidden values in the Word table for calculations. These tables used to be tied to a large and complex macro excel file.

**My Code**

```
  library("docxtractr")
  sourcesSummary <- lapply(files, function(x){
   doc <- read_docx(x)
   kingsTbls <- docx_extract_all_tbls(doc)
   sources <- docx_extract_tbl(doc, 6, header = FALSE)
   sources <- data.frame(sources)
   # The below two lines are the issue #
   sources[9,3:4] <- sources[9,2:3]
   sources[24,3:4] <- sources[24,2:3]
   })
```

`

**Default Data Frame**

```
                          V1         V2            V3       V4
1           SOURCES OF FUNDS     AMOUNT      PER UNIT     <NA>
2            Proposed A Loan         87 $7,208,000.00  $82,851
3            Proposed B Loan                    $0.00    $   0
4            Investor Equity            $1,948,362.00  $22,395
5   Operating Partner Equity                    $0.00    $   0
6                      Other                    $0.00    $   0
7                      Other                    $0.00    $   0
8                      Other                    $0.00    $   0
9      TOTAL SOURCE OF FUNDS $9,156,362      $105,246     <NA>
10                                 <NA>          <NA>     <NA>
11             USES OF FUNDS     AMOUNT      PER UNIT     <NA>
12      Existing Mortgage(s)                       $0    $   0
13            Purchase Price               $9,011,000 $103,575
14          Origination Fees                  $54,060    $ 621
15        FM application Fee                   $7,208    $  83
16             Investor Fees                    $0.00    $   0
17             Closing Costs                    $0.00    $   0
18 Other (Yield Maintenance)                       $0    $   0
19      Capital Improvements               $39,650.00    $ 456
20            Processing Fee                $3,000.00    $  34
21               Third Party               $11,000.00    $ 126
22                     Legal               $12,500.00    $ 144
23    Repair Escrow (Funded)                    $0.00    $   0
24        TOTAL USE OF FUNDS $9,138,418      $105,039     <NA>
25                                 <NA>          <NA>     <NA>
26        CASH OUT/(CASH IN)        132       $17,944    $ 207
```

**Problem:**

The issue I'm having revolves around moving/shifting values within a data frame. I have successfully done it within the console, however, when I run the same code within an **lapply** it doesn't execute properly.

I'm attempting to shift the values in rows 9 and 24 to the right, by one column.
Within the console, on a specific test variable the below code works fine, however it doesn't when I run the lapply over all my files.

**Problem Code**

```
   sources[9,3:4] <- sources[9,2:3]
   sources[24,3:4] <- sources[24,2:3]
```

I've also attempted to use `drop = FALSE` within the brackets and that doesn't work either.

**Current output with lapply**

```
           V2       V3
24 $9,138,418 $105,039
```

**Desired Output**

Note that rows 9 and 24 have changed. When I run my code within the console on a specific data frame this is the produced result, again the lapply seems to be the issue. Afterwards I am going to delete the 2nd column and the NA rows too.

```
                          V1         V2            V3       V4
1           SOURCES OF FUNDS     AMOUNT      PER UNIT     <NA>
2            Proposed A Loan         87 $7,208,000.00  $82,851
3            Proposed B Loan                    $0.00    $   0
4            Investor Equity            $1,948,362.00  $22,395
5   Operating Partner Equity                    $0.00    $   0
6                      Other                    $0.00    $   0
7                      Other                    $0.00    $   0
8                      Other                    $0.00    $   0
9      TOTAL SOURCE OF FUNDS               $9,156,362 $105,246
10                                 <NA>          <NA>     <NA>
11             USES OF FUNDS     AMOUNT      PER UNIT     <NA>
12      Existing Mortgage(s)                       $0    $   0
13            Purchase Price               $9,011,000 $103,575
14          Origination Fees                  $54,060    $ 621
15        FM application Fee                   $7,208    $  83
16             Investor Fees                    $0.00    $   0
17             Closing Costs                    $0.00    $   0
18 Other (Yield Maintenance)                       $0    $   0
19      Capital Improvements               $39,650.00    $ 456
20            Processing Fee                $3,000.00    $  34
21               Third Party               $11,000.00    $ 126
22                     Legal               $12,500.00    $ 144
23    Repair Escrow (Funded)                    $0.00    $   0
24        TOTAL USE OF FUNDS               $9,138,418 $105,039
25                                 <NA>          <NA>     <NA>
26        CASH OUT/(CASH IN)        132       $17,944    $ 207
```

Thanks in advance for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last expression evaluated by a function is returned by the function. In your case, that is `sources[24,3:4] <- sources[24,2:3]`, which is why you just get,

```
           V2       V3
24 $9,138,418 $105,039
```

The solution is to either explicitly return `sources` by adding `return(sources)` at the end of your function, or just to add `sources`.  So, your code should look like this:

```
library("docxtractr")
sourcesSummary <- lapply(files, function(x){
   doc <- read_docx(x)
   kingsTbls <- docx_extract_all_tbls(doc)
   sources <- docx_extract_tbl(doc, 6, header = FALSE)
   sources <- data.frame(sources)
   # The below two lines are the issue #
   sources[9,3:4] <- sources[9,2:3]
   sources[24,3:4] <- sources[24,2:3]
   sources #<- New code!
   })
```